# JavaFX - Hide/Disable Mac OS X Menu

Tags: java, macos, javafx, fullscreen

I'm developing a game in JavaFX and I would like the game to be run in full-screen mode. If I use primaryStage.setFullScreen(true) it gets the screen in full-screen mode, but if I press Esc it leaves the full-screen mode or if I move the mouse to the upper side of the screen OS X menu bar and window upper border appear.

Is there any way to run JavaFX application in real full-screen mode?
So, without OS X menu bar and the upper window border.

Sincere thanks!
Mitja